# get_term_by() returning null on plugin

Tags: plugin-development, functions, hooks

I'm creating a woocommerce product category using Guzzle on my plugin, that i was able to do, but then when i try to get the terms of this category, using the function **get_term_by()**, always **return null**, unless i refresh the page, but i need to get this data righ after the product category is created.

The call for the function that create the product category and get the terms is made with AJAX following the WordPress Plugin Developer Handbook.

Here is the pieces of the code im using for it: (the above code is not on the same file, just put it together here)

```php
class Category {
    /**
     * Create products category
     */
    public function create(string $name, string $description, $parent)
    {
        $response = $this->client->request('POST', '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?consumer_key=' . $this->consumerKey . '&consumer_secret=' . $this->consumerSecret, [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => [
                'name' => $name,
                'description' => $description,
                'parent' => $parent
            ],
            ['debug' => true]
        ]);

        return $response->getBody();
    }
}

/**
 * Instantiating the class and create the product category
 */
$woocommerceCategory = new Category($clientWoocommerceCategory, $woocommerceConsumerKey, $woocommerceConsumerSecret);
$woocommerceCategory->create($name, $description, 0);

/**
 * Abstract class Utils
 */
abstract class Utils
{
    /**
     * check if category name exists
     */
    public static function categoryExists(string $name): bool
    {
        $category = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');

        if ($category) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * get category id by name
     */
    public static function getCategoryIdByName(string $name)
    {
        $category = get_term_by('name', $name, 'product_cat');

        return $category->term_id;
    }
}

/**
 * Abstract methods to get the terms
 */
$categoryId = Utils::getCategoryIdByName($name); //null
$categoryExists = Utils::categoryExists($name); //null
```

What am I missing here to be able to consult the product categories updated and get the terms of the product category that was just created?

Comment: is there a reason you're using a REST API HTTP request to yourself to create the term? This is _highly_ unusual and likely the cause of your problem. Unless the `client` is making the request to a different site, in which case the answer is obvious. Note that WooCommerce questions are offtopic here, this isn't a place to get help with WooCommerce/3rd party plugins. It also seems your class is incomplete, the `$this->client` is never created or instantiated, and `Utils` is an abstract class so technically it should be generating errors on use

Comment: @TomJNowell no specific reason to create the term using the Woocomerce REST API. I was able to get the term that was just created when the function for creating the term was wp_insert_category().

Comment: you shouldn't use HTTP requests to interact with your own site, it's very slow and consumes a lot more resources than calling the functions directly. It also provides no opportunities to clear out local caches